# c# MongoDB select list of fields from a field

Tags: c#, mongodb

Let's say i have this document structure stored in my MongoDB database.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f131f3c4ca7b044eb11171"),
    "services" : "gegsg",
    "validCertificateOrLicense" : {
        "title" : "asfasf",
        "number" : "fasfsdf",
        "dateIssued" : "fsdffsdfsdf",
        "validUntil" : "fsdfsdfd",
        "issuingAgency" : "fsdfsd"
    }
}
```

I wanted to list those fields in my Binding to be used on my DataGrid, I have tried to use the solutions posted on several stack questions. But none of them worked, i tried to check using Console.WriteLine(BindList.Count) to check whether the query works.

```
class facultyData
{

    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string services { get; set; }
    public List<certification> validCertificateOrLicense { get; set; }

}

class certification
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string dateIssued { get; set; }
    public string validUntil { get; set; }
    public string issuingAgency { get; set; }
}
```

This is one of solution that i have tried.

```
  var query =  collection.AsQueryable<facultyData>()
             .Where(c => c.validCertificateOrLicense.Any(d => d.stores.Count() == 1);
```

Or maybe there's a problem with my ToList code

```
List<facultyData> acadList = query1.ToList<facultyData>();   
        BindingList<facultyData> acadBinding = new BindingList<facultyData>(acadList);
```

Comment: d.stores.Count() does not map to any field in the certification entity. what data do you want to return in your query? If you remove that part of the query so your where clause is just .Where(c => c.validCertificateOrLicense.Any()); then the query should work.

Comment: @kevin Sorry my bad, already replaced the query. But it gives me a FileFormatException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `facultyData` contains a list of certifications in the `validCertificateOrLicense`  field. However your document structure in the DB only contains a single certificate in the `validCertificateOrLicense` field.

If your document structure in the DB is as follows then your query should work

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f131f3c4ca7b044eb11171"),
    "services" : "gegsg",
    "validCertificateOrLicense" : [{
        "title" : "asfasf",
        "number" : "fasfsdf",
        "dateIssued" : "fsdffsdfsdf",
        "validUntil" : "fsdfsdfd",
        "issuingAgency" : "fsdfsd"
    }]
}
```

Note - the `validCertificateOrLicense` field now contains an array of `certification` sub documents.

Alternatively you could change your c# entity to match the existing document structure in the DB. Your facultyData object would look as follows

```
class facultyData
{

    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string services { get; set; }
    public certification validCertificateOrLicense { get; set; }

}
```

Note - now the `validCertificateOrLicense` field only contains a single `certification` document.

Comment: Oh, thank you for making me realize my mistake, may the spirits of the codes be with you. But I changed the query to var query =  collection.AsQueryable<facultyData>().Where(c => c.validCertificateOrLicense.Any()); to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
 var acadList = Database.GetCollection<facultyData>("facultyData").AsQueryable().Where(f => f.validCertificateOrLicense.Any()).ToList();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it gives me FileFormatException, saying "An error occurred while deserializing the validCertificateOrLicense property of class WpfApplication1.facultyData: Expected element name to be '_t', not 'title'." @kayvan-karim